# php mongoDB sort string

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

im new to mongoDB and php, and yet im working on some project :D
so the issue that im having is that im unable to sort alpabeticly

```
var_dump($collection->find()->sort(array('title' => 1)));
```

output:

```
object(MongoCursor)#5 (0) { }
```

i have no idea what im doing wrong so please help

Comment: on a side note you are using the old php driver. http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php

Answer (score 0):

What You got is MongoCursor ... You shouldn't "vardump" it directly ... it's an object on which You can interate (foreach loop for example).

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php

On this link there is an example how to var_dump it properly :)

Comment: i figured it out, it sorts not database but cursor itself so it needs to be used in the place where i output data instead where i add it

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to transform it to array is to use iterator_to_array like this or loop using foreach:

```
$cursor = $collection->find()->sort(array('title' => 1));
$array = iterator_to_array($cursor);
var_dump($array);
```

or:

```
$cursor = $collection->find()->sort(array('title' => 1));
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc); // print each document
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: i thought that "sort" sorts database so i was using it after adding new items, but what it does, it sorts whatever cursor contains (if that makes sense)